# Выбор темы диплома

Tags: visual-studio, c++

Здравствуйте!

Я учусь в институте на программиста(4-й курс), пока про дипломное задание нам ничего не говорили.
Хочется знать что нужно будет делать... Какая тема диплома... Кто уже писал дипломные работы, можете озвучить на какую тему писали? В сети слышал, что можно и свою тему взять... 
Вот я и в раздумьях... На лабах в прошлом семестре писал приложение "Чат"(написал приложения: сервер, клиент). Долго писал. Наверно писать диплом еще сложней и дольше?
Пока в голову пришла такая идея: написать приложение которое позволяет зашивать любые файлы в картинки... Допустим есть документ, и есть 3 bmp картинки, мы их перетаскиваем в окно программы и кликаем что-то типа "зашить!" и программа сшивает данные... Потом можно будет вытащить из картинок файл... Всё это красиво оформить и качественно сделать... Но почему-то мне кажется что это на диплом не тянет... Как идея?

Comment: Что-то я не совсем понял, и что получается после сшивания?

Я бы еще понял такую идею: есть картинка (или видео). "Суем в нее" документ. Получаем очень похожую (если смотреть стандартным viewером) картинку.

Смотрим своей программой - видим документ (и исходную картинку).

Или это то же, что и Вы описали, но чуть другими словами?

--

Тянет ли на диплом? Зависит от того, что получится (и кто будет оценивать).

Comment: Да-да, это стенографией называется) Ну, получиться должно удобное приложение, которое сшивает данные с bmp картинкой(картинками).

Comment: @Alerr, *[стенография](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F)* это другое

Comment: ) Описался, стеганография. Ну вообщем смысл Вы верно поняли.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alerr, имхо, ерунда. больше подходит для лабораторной для первокурсника, чем для дипломного проекта.
Берут, как правило, что-то более крупное и масштабное (однако не слишком - нужно трезво оценивать свои силы и возможности). Можете попытаться решить какую-нибудь проблему в Computer Science, или развить методы решения уже существующей.
Вообще все сильно зависит от того, на какой специальности вы учитесь.
Если учитесь на программиста, то значит в дипломной работе Вы должны доказать что умеете писать компьютерные программы, значит должны создать некий программный продукт - какой, уже выбор за вами. 
Мождете удариться в науку или написать что-то очень сложное - а-ля распознание лиц с помощью методов локальных дескрипторов или написать программу симуляции какого-нибудь физического либо химического процесса (-ов).
Вообще, по-идее, процесс обучения в ВУЗе как бы должен подразумевать под собой научную работу (ну это я так думаю), поэтому и дипломная работа, как мне кажется, должна представлять собой результат научной работы - описание нового алгоритма (или доработка и\или оценка уже существующих).

У нас к примеру почти не было тем, как-то связанных с научной работой, больше с практикой - разработать устройство, выполняющие соответсвующие функции, и программу к нему. Были также и темы по проектированию компьютерных сетей и "даже" по написанию сайта интернет-магазина на php.

Comment: >имхо, ерунда. больше подходит для лабораторной для первокурсника

то есть вы, надо полагать, сможете без проблем реализовать это два академических часа?

Comment: Ну, у нас была лаба по сетям: снифферы, генераторы ip. Так там времени порядочно ушло... На это приложение, думаю, чуть меньше времени уйдет. Больше на оформление и красоту. И исследования как такового можно сказать что нет.

Comment: @Alerr, вот про время и отсутствие исследования, IMHO Вы заблуждаетесь.

Я, правда, не занимался такими темами, но мне кажется, что выбрать подходящие биты в картинке (т.е. биты, изменение которых слабо влияет на ее восприятие человеком) не очень просто.

Или Вы предполагаете просто тупо дописать один файл в конец другого?

Comment: Аааа, ну если так) А это идея) Я по началу думал, что можно всё в альфа цвет вписать(в картинке bmp альфа цвет содержит мусор)

Answer (score 0):

В дипломе важна экономическая эффективность. Если твоим приложением действительно кто-то будет пользоваться, то считай это хорошей темой.

Comment: Вот я и думаю, что кому-то может пригодится.

Comment: Но при этом я бы семь раз подумал, в самом ли деле мне хочется тесно контактировать с людьми, которые *действительно* будут такую штуку использовать.

Comment: Не, зачем контактировать. Просто будет что сказать при сдаче. Типа, вот придумал, пригодится тем-то людям и для того-то. И пока ничего подобного не было, и придраться, что списал не смогут.